# NMaximize in Mathematica equivalent in Python

Tags: python, optimization, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find a equivalent of "NMaximize" optimization command in Mathematica in Python. I tried googling but did not help much.

Comment: If would be easier for someone to answer if you described what this function does in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mathematica docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) describe the methods usable within `NMaximize` as: `Possible settings for the Method option include "NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing", and "RandomSearch".`.

Have a look at [scipy's optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) which also supports:

- NelderMead
- DifferentialEvolution
- and much more...

It is very important to find the correct tool for *your optimization problem*! This is at least dependent on:

- Discrete variables?
- Smooth optimization function?
- Linear, Conic, Non-convex optimization problem?
- and again: much more...

Compared to Mathematica's approach, you will have to choose the method a-priori within scipy (at some extent).

Comment: We used DifferentialEvolution and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @VIDHYASHREE Glad you found something!